# Out of memory exception while uploading audio in windows phone

Tags: c#

I have recorded audio .wav file using c# and I am trying to upload it to get the response from the server. and my issue is small size of audio file is getting uploaded properly but when I upload larger size audio like (10 min), im getting system out of memory exception. the above code is the illustration for getting response from api. Please help if there is any solution.

Below I have uploaded my entire code.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    private MicrophoneRecorder _recorder = new MicrophoneRecorder();
    private IsolatedStorageFileStream _audiostream;
    private string _tempfilename = "tempWav.wav";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void RecordAudio_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayAudio.IsEnabled = false;
        btnupload.IsEnabled = false;
        _recorder.Start();

    }

    private void RecordAudio_Unchecked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _recorder.Stop();
        SaveTempAudio(_recorder.Buffer);
        PlayAudio.IsEnabled = true;
        btnupload.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
    {

        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Attempting to save an empty sound buffer");

        if (_audiostream != null)
        {
            AudioPlayer.Stop();
            AudioPlayer.Source = null;
            _audiostream.Dispose();

        }



        using (IsolatedStorageFile isostore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if(isostore.FileExists(_tempfilename))
                isostore.DeleteFile(_tempfilename);

            _tempfilename = string.Format("{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());


            var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(_recorder.SampleRate);

            IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = isostore.CreateFile(_tempfilename);
            isostream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            AudioPlayer.SetSource(isostream);

        }
    }

    private void btnplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AudioPlayer.Play();


    }

    private void btnupload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        _audiostream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_tempfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
        Uri songuri= new Uri(_tempfilename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata metaData = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata();
        metaData.AlbumName = "Album name" +" "+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
        metaData.ArtistName = "Artist Name" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        metaData.GenreName = "test" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        metaData.Name = "SongName" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        var library = new MediaLibrary();
        var song = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(library, songuri, metaData, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_audiostream);
        SendRequest("http://demosites.ephronsystems.com/timeseries/index.php/v1/report/reportFileUpload", reader.BaseStream);

    }

    public void SendRequest(string URL, Stream fileStream)
    {


        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(URL, Method.POST);


        request.AddFile("file_source", ReadToEnd(fileStream), "test.wav");

        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

        restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                String res = response.Content;
                MessageBox.Show(res);
            }


            else
            {
                string error = response.ErrorException.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(error);

            }
        });

    }

    // Imgae convert to byte array
    public static byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        long originalPosition = stream.Position;
        stream.Position = 0;

        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                {
                    int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                    if (nextByte != -1)
                    {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                        readBuffer = temp;
                        totalBytesRead++;
                    }
                }
            }

            byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
            if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
            {
                buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Position = originalPosition;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with `RestRequest` but I had the same problem with `HttpWebRequest`, so maybe `RestRequest` implements it. To solve the problem with `HttpWebRequest` you have to set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` to `false`. Details of the problem are here: [A POST or PUT request may fail when you use the HttpWebRequest class](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573)

There's a catch though, you then need to specify the exact content-length of your POST manually before generating the request, so you need to know the byte[] length of your file and your headers and add this value to your request. It's a bit of a mare to implement, but it does work. This post details the workaround: [Uploading large HTTP multipart request](http://www.techcoil.com/blog/uploading-large-http-multipart-request-with-system-net-httpwebrequest-in-c/)

Hope this helps.